# Why do my styled component keyframes error with ts-styled-plugin(9999) in react when using percentage instead of TO/FROM

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using CRA 4, when using keyframes with styled components, percentages cause an error that I cannot seem to understand why - but doesn't error if I use To / From.

this is the example:

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'

const animateLeft = keyframes`
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
`
```

Used inside a styled component as such:

```
animation: ${animateLeft} 1s infinite;
```

The error I get with the percentages inside the keyframes are:

```
} expectedts-styled-plugin(9999)
```

Why?

Comment: believe this may be due to vscode-styled-components plugin, have had to disable it in VSCode.

Comment: There's a PR that addresses the issue >> https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-styled-plugin/issues/137.

Answer (score 5):

There is an ongoing problem with this for others too. You can follow that here: https://github.com/styled-components/vscode-styled-components/issues/293

In the meantime if you have keyframes that have 0% and 100%, just use `from` and `to`:

**Temporary solutions** (before team on VS gets done):

```js
keyframes`
  \ 0%{
    <someCss>
  }

  \ 50% {
    <someCss>
  }

  \ 100% {
    <someCss>
  }
`;
```

Or:

```js
keyframes`
  ${'0%'} {
    <someCss>
  }

  ${'50%'} {
    <someCss>
  }

  ${'100%'} {
    <someCss>
  }
`;
```

In case you have the one you mentioned with multiple stops you will need to disable plugin for VS code for styled components.

**UPDATE**

Bug is now fixed with newest version of `vscode-styled-components` extension v1.6.4. Just update your extension and all will be ok.

**EDIT**

Currently PR is in progress for fixing this problem i will edit this answer when it is done: https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-styled-plugin/issues/137#issuecomment-848930098

Follow up this issue and when extension gets updated you will be able to use this without error: https://github.com/styled-components/vscode-styled-components/issues/301

Comment: thanks for this, will keep an eye on the open issue. Unfortunately, my keyframes require the in-between of 0 -100% so the error will always show - will await the changes!

Comment: Yea. I can see a progress there. They made a PR and we are waiting for it. I can update my answer when it gets ready

Comment: @narliecholler I made an edit to my answer for a temporary solution for the error. PR is still in work

Comment: @narliecholler problem is now fixed with newest version of extension 1.6.4. So just update it (it requires restart of VS Code) and all is good. Cheers